# Append text to a submitted search form

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a search box on a page that opens up a checkout page with the results of the search on submit.

```
    <form action="<?php echo $url; ?>" method="post" id="domain-search-form" onSubmit="return validateDomainSearch($(this))">
        <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="search" />
            <input type="hidden" name="serviceplan_id" value="<?php echo $serviceplan_id ; ?>" />
            <input id="domain" type="search" name="domain" placeholder="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" value="<?php echo $domain_value; ?>" />
            <button type="submit" onClick="$(this).parent('form').submit()">Search Domains</button>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="domain-search-error error">Please enter a domain name.</div>
    </form>
```

What I would to do is append some text to the search request.

So for example if I search mydomainname, I would like the result to be mydomainname.co.uk.

Comment: Append the text to domain textbox using jquery before calling the submit method. onClick="$("#domain").val($("#domain").val()+".co.uk");$(this).parent‌​('form').submit()" 

is that something you are expecting?

Comment: hmm... looks like it should work, but for me the .co.uk isn't being added to the search.

Comment: Correction, works perfectly... Just needed to escape the double quotes.
Thanks for answering. +1

Comment: Adding the comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append the text to domain textbox using jquery before calling the submit method.

```
onClick="$('#domain').val($('#domain').val()+'.co.uk');$(this).parent‌​('form').‌​submit()"
```